# Bluetooth BT-201 device disconnects immediately after connected

Tags: 18.04, drivers, 20.04, sound, bluetooth

I bought a new BT audio device (Seisa BT-201), but I cannot make it work in any of my linuxes boxes (Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04, Debian 10). It simply disconnects immediately after it connects (trying several times after pairing). It does work like charm with my mobile phone (Android). Also, I know this computer can connect to another BT audio device, so the BT device and its drivers are OK.

I did try several of the different options I saw in similar posts here, but to no avail.

Some details on the computer I'm working now are:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-1103-oem

$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i dist
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"

$ bt-adapter -i
[hci0]
  Name: beta-Inspiron-3480
  Address: EC:5C:68:64:62:48
  Alias: beta-Inspiron-3480 [rw]
  Class: 0x1c010c
  Discoverable: 0 [rw]
  DiscoverableTimeout: 0 [rw]
  Discovering: 0
  Pairable: 1 [rw]
  PairableTimeout: 0 [rw]
  Powered: 1 [rw]
  UUIDs: [HeadsetAudioGateway, 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, AVRemoteControl, OBEXFileTransfer, 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, OBEXObjectPush, PnPInformation, AVRemoteControlTarget, IrMCSync, AudioSource, AudioSink, 00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001, 00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, PhoneBookAccess, 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, Headset]

$ lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
    enter code here

$ lsmod | grep -i 'bluetooth\|btusb\|wl'
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             516096  43 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
```

`hcidump` shows:

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.48
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
    status 0x00 handle 2 bdaddr A9:F6:16:4E:13:C7 type ACL encrypt 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Read Remote Supported Features (0x0b) plen 11
    status 0x00 handle 2
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x8d 0xfa 0x88 0x2d 0x79 0x83
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Read Remote Extended Features (0x23) plen 13
    status 0x00 handle 2 page 1 max 1
    Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Remote Name Req Complete (0x07) plen 255
    status 0x00 bdaddr A9:F6:16:4E:13:C7 name 'BT-201'
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Authentication Requested (0x01|0x0011) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10
    Link Key Request Reply (0x01|0x000b) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 bdaddr A9:F6:16:4E:13:C7
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7
    Read RSSI (0x05|0x0005) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 handle 2 rssi -24
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7
    Read Link Quality (0x05|0x0003) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 handle 2 lq 255
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7
    Read Transmit Power Level (0x03|0x002d) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 handle 2 level 10
> HCI Event: Auth Complete (0x06) plen 3
    status 0x00 handle 2
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Set Connection Encryption (0x01|0x0013) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Encrypt Change (0x08) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 2 encrypt 0x01
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 7
    Read Encryption Key Size (0x05|0x0008) ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 2 reason 0x13
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection
```

Finally, the `syslog`:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i bluetooth
Feb  5 18:59:11 computer bluetoothd[964]: Unable to select SEP
```

Happy to answer any question. Thanks in advance to any of you reading.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work in the end, by pure luck! Here are the steps to make it work (I got it working in the three systems listed above):

1. From a terminal, launch `bluetoothctl`. This is a REPL (like a terminal) for bluetooth commands.
2. Issue `scan on` and wait a bit. Your device ID should appear (mine is A9:F6:16:4E:13:C7).
3. Issue `trust <id>` (replace `<id>` with your own device ID).
4. Issue `connect <id>`. This command will fail, but that's OK.
5. Do the IT Crowd's speciality: turn off your device and turn it back on.
6. The device should connect automatically! If not, try step 4, and if that doesn't work, then you probably have a different issue than mine.